# Pytorch Pre-trained RESNET18 Model

Tags: python, pytorch

I have trained a pre-trained RESNET18 model in pytorch and saved it. While testing the model is giving different accuracy for different mini-batch size. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think so. 
RESNET contains batch normalisation layers. At evaluation time you need to fix these; otherwise the running means are continuously being adjusted after processing each batch hence giving you different accuracy .

Try setting:

```
model.eval()
```

before evaluation. Note before getting back into training, call `model.train()`.

Comment: I forgot to update the thread with the answer. That was precisely what worked. Thank You.